# Ошибка. TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str (pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

не могу решить проблему, может кто-то сталкивался.
Смотрел на других источниках и не пришел к решению..

В чем задача стоит, надо понять почему появляется ошибка и как от нее избавиться. И вроде как после этого должна нормально работать анимация персонажа, т.е. будет вид словно он бежит.

```
import pygame
pygame.init(); #нинциализируем билиотеку

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1250,650))#размерность нашего игрового окна
pygame.display.set_caption("Моя новая игра")#имя программы

#подгружааем картинки для использования
walkRight = [pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk0.png"),("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk1.png"),("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk2.png")
                            ,("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk3.png"),("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk4.png"),("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk5.png")]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk0.png"),("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk1.png"),("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk2.png")
                            ,("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk3.png"),("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk4.png"),("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk5.png")]
playerStand = pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/stand.png")
bg = pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/bg.jpg")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = 50#начальаня координата нашего персонажа
y = 387
wight = 192#ширина персонажа
heigh = 256#высота персонажа
speed = 5#скорость персонажа

isJump = False#прыгает сейчас игрок или нет
left = False
right = False
jumpCount = 10
animCount = 0

def drawWindow():#функция отрисовки окна игры
    global animCount
    if animCount + 1 >= 30:
        animCount = 0
    win.blit(bg,(0,0))#установка бк
#анимируем персонажа
    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[animCount // 5], (x,y))
        animCount +=1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[animCount // 5], (x,y))
        animCount +=1
    else:
        win.blit(playerStand, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()#для обновления формы

run = True#условие для работы игры пока мы не нажмем на выход
while run:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()#картеж для записи всех действий
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x >5:#если нажимаем на кнопку влево то от X отноманием нашу скорость(x>5 - что-бы не уходить за границы игрового поля)
        x -= speed
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 1250 -wight -5:#x < 500 -wight -5 - что-бы не уходить за границы игрового поля
        x += speed
        left = False
        right = True
    else:
        left = False
        right = False
        animCount =0
    if not(isJump):#если не прыгает
#Реализуем прыжек
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            if jumpCount < 0:
                y += (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            else:
                y -= (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

    drawWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Вот код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/79132/Desktop/python/game.py", line 80, in <module>
    drawWindow()
  File "C:/Users/79132/Desktop/python/game.py", line 38, in drawWindow
    win.blit(walkRight[animCount // 5], (x,y))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str
```

ошибка происходит после движения более чем на пару пикселей, но при этом если не зажимать кнопку движения а нажимать и отпускать то все работает более менее адекватно.

Comment: Ошибка означает то, что вы передаете объект типа `str`, а не `pygame.Surface`

Comment: я это прочитал и понял, но как исправить не знаю

Comment: Передавать объект нужного типа?)

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример, демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Comment: Я не знаю что за тип он просит и как сделать все верно.

Comment: Я описал проблему в конце темы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

то что я заметит, так это опечатка при формировании списков `walkRight` и `walkLeft`.

Добавьте `pygame.image.load` ко всем элементам списка.

```
...
#подгружааем картинки для использования
walkRight = [
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk0.png"),
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk1.png"),
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk2.png"),
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk3.png"),
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk4.png"),
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/left_walk5.png")
]

walkLeft = [
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk0.png"),
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk1.png"),
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk2.png"),
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk3.png"),
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk4.png"),
    pygame.image.load("game/firstGamePyGame/right_walk5.png")
]
...
```